# Getting Bean instance as null using Strategy Design Pattern and @Autowired

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, autowired, strategy-pattern

Hi I am trying to use Strategy Design pattern. I am getting ReEncryptionOperation bean as null in my TestServiceImpl class.

this is my interface

```
public interface ReEncryptionOperation {

    void performOperation (String name);
}
```

These are my implementation classes

```
public class Test1 implements ReEncryptionOperation {


@Override
public void performOperation(String name){

    return ....;
   }
}


public class Test2 implements ReEncryptionOperation {


@Override
public void performOperation(String name) {

    return ....;
}
}
```

This is my configuration class where I am defining as a bean

```
  @Configuration
  @Slf4j
  public class TestConfiguration
  {
   @Bean("reEncryptionOperation")
  public ReEncryptionOperation getReEncryptionOperation () throws ReEncryptionException {

    if (annotationSupport) {
        return new Test1();
    }
    return new Test2();
}

 }
```

this is my service class where i am trying to use ReEncryptionOperation using @Autowired. But I am getting null.

```
 @Component
@Slf4j
 public class TestServiceImpl
 {

@Autowired
private ReEncryptionOperation reEncryptionOperation;



public ReEncryptionResponse submitJob (
    final ReEncryptionRequest reEncryptionRequest) throws ReEncryptionException
{
        reEncryptionOperation.performOperation(test);
        
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems ok.
Check that `TestConfiguration` is located in a package scanned by spring.

To be sure your bean is created on runtime, place a breakpoint in the method `getReEncryptionOperation`